# how to access cucumber.io report URL programatically after all tests runs

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

I have working maven project with java-selenium-testng-cucumber, cucumber publishes the report on https://reports.cucumber.io/reports and generated unique URL every time after running on tests by using this  publish = true flag in cucumberoptions.

Now, I need to access this generated URL programmatically somehow after all test runs and send that link in an email.

***View your Cucumber Report at: https://reports.cucumber.io/reports/a3b6bbca***

This is how my runnner looks

> import io.cucumber.testng.AbstractTestNGCucumberTests; import
> io.cucumber.testng.CucumberOptions;
>
> @CucumberOptions(features = "src/test/java"
> ,glue = { "stepsdefination" },
> monochrome = true,
> publish = true)
>
> public class Main_Runner extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests { }

Can someone guide how can i do it programmatically since i don't see any way to do it by accessing some methods from cucumber ?